# Properties resolver in Spring

Tags: spring

I am having following properties in a file-

```
dir.path=path/of/directory
file.path=${dir.path}/file_name
```

In Spring Bean, I am referring it as given below -

```
@Value("${file.path}")
String filePath;
```

However filePath is set by Spring as '${dir.path}/file_name' and it does not resolved completely. I am using Java Configuration ( no  xml). I will appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: What is the value of dir.path that is being injected?

Comment: Value of filePath is having ${dir.path} as it is. It was not resolved. When I tried to inject dir.path value to another property, it was populated correctly. Thanks

Comment: can you post your how you config your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?